# NL Hold Em coming into the blind

Tags: poker-theory

In a cash game.  The button is on seat 10, seat 1 is the small blind and seat 2 is the big blind.  Both seat 2 and seat 3 bust out and are not rebuying into the game.  Only 1 player is coming to sit down, does it matter if he chooses seat 2 or seat 3?  Either way, seat 1 will be the button and the new player will be big blind only.

Thank you

Chris

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on the casino or cardroom you are playing at, some have different house rules.

With that said from my experience it doesn't matter which seat he picks, he will be big blind and the game will continue as normal. This is by far the normal in most places I have played and dealt in.

I have dealt in places that did it a little different. I have seen some places let him be the SB and seat 4 will be the BB, I thought this was silly personally but house rules. I've also seen places make the player either wait or buy the button straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, most of the time the dealer will skip the new player if they come in and they have to wait until the button gets to them. (This is to avoid making the same player pay the BB twice in a row) In that case, it doesn't matter at all which seat they pick. In this case, I believe they would be in the position to get the button in 2 hands, so they would only have to sit out for one.

Comment: Why would the player be skipped? No one in this situation will have to pay a BB twice, both players who should have been the blinds are gone. Seat 4 would be BB by him/herself anyway.

Comment: Because seat 1 is the dealer, there is no SB, and seat 4 is BB. If the new player sits down right away he would be in the SB seat. My understanding is that when you sit down you pay the BB, so he would either have to pay the BB, or wait. I suppose this could vary depending on where you play though.

Comment: I got the impression the next hand hadn't started in his situation. But I see your point anyway :)

Comment: I play in LA and Vegas. Most cases I have seen the dealer would skip the new player and tell him he would have to wait 1 hand. Then freeze the button on seat 10 and seat 3 & 4 would post a BB.  And the next hand button to seat 3 & post SB, seat 4 post SB, and seat 5 post BB.